# How to revoke an App permission to access OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive

So I'm a developer, and I'm testing App access to OneDrive in a Windows Phone 10 emulator.

The thing is that once I logged in the first time to OneDrive and gave the app permission, I can't find where to revoke this access to force the app to show the login screen again. It keeps getting the cached authorization token and skipping the login process. And I still need to debug this process a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this from the phone itself, but you can revoke access to your MS account online. To do so, log in at https://account.microsoft.com and select "Privacy" from the menu. Scroll down, and under "Apps and services" click on "Apps and services that can access your data". Alternatively, use [this direct link](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage). There you'll see a list of all apps and services that have access to your Microsoft account. Click on the name of your app and then "Remove these permissions".

Note that this will remove **all** permissions that app has to your MS account, not just to OneDrive. There doesn't seem to be a way to selectively revoke permissions like you can on your phone.

Comment: direct link to the manage permissions webpage: https://account.live.com/consent/Manage

Comment: "Security & Privacy" is no longer an option. I could only find it via the direct link listed.

Comment: @PeterX I've updated the answer, to reflect the new layout of the MS account pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the app permissions you've given in your [Microsoft account](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage).